# Shorter way to check if true in Python list comprehension expression?

Tags: python

Is it possible to write it shorter? I am mostly interested in **not writing *`r[0].value`* twice**. The alternative **must be shorter**.

```
(r[0].value for r in sheet.range(USERROLELIST) if r[0].value)
```

`if r[0].value` -- to check that it != None

`sheet.range` is from openpyxl module.

Comment: this isn't code golf...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way of writing it, however I much prefer the code you have given

```
filter(None, (r[0].value for r in sheet.range(USERROLELIST)))
```

Comment: good for long attribute names, but in this case we have the same lenght

Comment: @Sergey11g this isn't perl ;)

Comment: @Sergey11g are you trying to reduce length of code, or performance impact? is indexing somehow very expensive? or are you just speculatively optimising?

Comment: Caught myself writing (x for x if x) many times

Comment: @Sergey11g there's nothing wrong with that

Comment: But will r[0].value be called 2 times in this case (x for x if x)?
And in case of using filter()?

Comment: @Sergey11g `r[0].value` is accessed once here but twice in your example code

Comment: The wrong thing here was accessing twice.

Comment: @Sergey11g both this solution and InbarRose's access it only once

Comment: Actually it's strange that there's nothing like `(r[0].value as v for r in sheet.range(USERROLELIST) if v)`. It would certainly help DRY.

Comment: yes, would be cool to have aliases. Maybe in Python 4...

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
(r for r in (R[0].value for R in sheet.range(USERROLELIST)) if r)
```

---

If you really want to make things with the "least amount of characters possible"

You can try something like this:

First of all, import your modules with shorter names...

```
from openpyxl import sheet
sr = sheet.range
```

Secondly, have shorter variable names:

```
L = USERROLELIST
```

Finally, do away with extra whitespace:

```
(r for r in(R[0].value for R in sr(L))if r)
```

Comment: it's longer than the original

Comment: But it is faster.... If you want the least amount of characters it would probably be very inefficient...

Comment: @InbarRose I don't think this would be faster than OP's code

Comment: It is because you only look up `R[0].value` once per iteration instead of twice.

Comment: >>once per iteration instead of twice
How is it comparing to filter()?

Comment: @Sergey11g yes, only once. You can check it yourself using `timeit`.

Comment: Which one is better/faster? Filter() or this one?

Comment: @Sergey11g `filter` is likely to be faster but don't let that fool you, the difference will be negligable

Comment: Sure, understand. Thanks, the last one is also good, but not so easy to read when there are one-symbol variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools
gen = itertools.ifilter(lambda x: x[0].value, sheet.range(USERROLELIST))

#later...
for i in gen:
    # do something with i
```

This method reduces temp copy overhead